# Composite-primary key issue in entity framework code first

Tags: entity-framework, composite-primary-key

I have an issue in entity framework code first, three table in database as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [Food](
PK [FoodId] [int] NOT NULL,
[FoodName] [varchar](50) NULL)

CREATE TABLE [Fruit](
PK [FruitId] [int] NOT NULL,
[FruitName] [varchar](50) NULL)

CREATE TABLE [FoodFruit](
PK, FK [FoodId] [int] NOT NULL,
PK, FK [FruitId] [int] NOT NULL)
```

The Model will only generate Food, Fruit entities.

But if I add a new column [Notes] to FoodFruit table, such as Notes:

```
CREATE TABLE [FoodFruit](
PK, FK [FoodId] [int] NOT NULL,
PK, FK [FruitId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Notes] [varchar](50) NULL)
```

The Model will generate Food, Fruit and FoodFruit entities.

So, I'm confused it, why the first one doesn't generate the FoodFruit entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct behavior. In the first case your FoodFruit table is just database helper to model many-to-many relationship. EF doesn't need such helper in conceptual model so it hides this table behind directly modeled many-to-many relation. In the second case the table has additional data - it becomes full entity, not just junction table for relationship. EF detects it and map it as a new class.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply.I still have a question. In the first case, if I want to insert or update data to FoodFruit table, however it turns out that the entity of FoodFruit does not exists,what should I do?

Comment: Food and Fruit should have navigation properties - collection of related entities and you will just add item to that collection.